# How can I get the characters between 2 other characters?

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a string which at some point contains the set of characters in the following format `[123]`.

What I would like to do is get the characters between `[]` but the characters in between are never the same length.

How would I go about this in VB.NET?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Dim s As String = "foo [123]=ro bar"
Dim i As Integer = s.IndexOf("[")
Dim f As String = s.Substring(i + 1, s.IndexOf("]", i + 1) - i - 1)
```

Comment: The string I'm passing specifically whilst debugging is `nav[1]=root`,  but when using the above, `f` is returned as `[1]=ro`. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: try this.. s.Substring(i, s.Length - (i + s.IndexOf("]", i + 1)))

Comment: @Liam: Sorry, my mistake. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim s As String = "nav[1]=root"
dim result as String = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("[") + 1, s.IndexOf("]", s.IndexOf("[")) - s.IndexOf("[") - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression.

```
    Dim s, result As String
    Dim r As RegularExpressions.Regex

    s = "aaa[bbbb]ccc"
    r = New RegularExpressions.Regex("\[([^\]]*)\]")

    If r.IsMatch(s) Then
        result = r.Match(s).Value
    Else
        result = ""
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

the statement  `RegularExpressions.Regex("\[([^\]]*)\]")` will returns the value inside bracket **And**  the bracket its self!

I have used this statement to return the IPAddress surrounded by () inside long string:-

```
Dim IPRegEx As Regex = New Regex("(?<=\().*?(?=\))")
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
Dim s As String = "nav[1]=root"
dim result as String = s.substring(s.indexof("[")+1, s.indexof("]")-s.indexof("[")-1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this..

```
Dim val As String = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2) // replace str with your string variable
```

Comment: The OP has a string *"which at some point"* has those characters. They don't make up the entire string.

Comment: So its sensible enough to replace s with the string variable which the OP has.

Comment: And then your code won't work. For example, if the OP's string is *"foo [123] bar"*.

Comment: OP never mentioned anything about that.. he only mentioned about the length of characters between the brackets.