# vb.net get text between <> brackets

Tags: vb.net, string, brackets

I am building a tool for Autodesk Inventor that works with an expression string.

```
=Pipe Ø<Pipe_OD> x <Pipe_t> - lg. <Pipe_length>mm
```

The text between <...> can be almost anything it's what the user made as input so these values are not fixed. And the number of <...> in the string can vary from 0 to 5.

What I would like to have as result for this string is following:

A converted string where the values between the <...> are replaced by number with an ascending value.

```
=Pipe Ø<1> x <2> - lg. <3>mm
```

And a `string()` where the values that are replaced by the numbers (above) are stored in.

I found a method that can work for strings with 1 `<...>` in the string but now that the quantity is variable I'm clueless about how I can do this.

[Link to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955882/how-can-i-get-the-characters-between-2-other-characters)

Comment: You mean you want a String like `"<pipe_val1> <pipe_val2> <pipe_val3>"` to be changed to  `"<0> <1> <2>"`and then have a collection of Strings where `myVals(0) = "pipe_val1"`, `myVals(1) = "pipe_val2"`, and `myVals(2) = "pipe_val3"`?

Comment: Yes, just like that!

Comment: Have you tried with Regex ? Can you show what you did to have 1 pair ?

Comment: I haven't tried Regex. I don't know what that is or does. I will look into it. What I did was pretty simple find the position of `<` and the position of `>` between those positions is the string, but that only works when 1 item is available?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with regular expressions, especially in .NET, but you can get the matches as a collection

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Added to my answer with regular expressions. Nice and clean now, but will probably break if the user starts adding < or >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: New answer with regular expressions (much better, will still have problems with additional < and > though)

```
    Dim s As String = "abc <pipe_val1> 123 <pipe_val2> &*( <pipe_val3>k"
    Dim myValues As New List(Of String)

    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(s, "<(.|\n)*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    Dim totalDiff As Integer = 0
    Dim idx As Integer = 0

    For Each ma As Match In matches
        Dim realIndex = ma.Index - totalDiff
        s = s.Remove(realIndex, ma.Length).Insert(realIndex, "<" & idx.ToString & ">")
        idx += 1
        totalDiff += ma.Length - (idx.ToString.Count + 2)
        myValues.Add(ma.Value.Trim({"<"c, ">"c}))
    Next
```

`"abc <pipe_val1> 123 <pipe_val2> &*( <pipe_val3>"` will be changed to `"abc <0> 123 <1> &*( <2>"` and `myValues` will contain "pipe_val1", "pipe_val2" and "pipe_val3"

Comment: Hi, thanks for that regex code, it's good, but i'm quite confused by the string insert and piece. would it not be easier to replace the string rather than remove and insert? `s.Replace(ma.Value, "<" & idx & ">")` ?

Comment: `.Replace` could cause issues because it will replace all occurancesof the substring. So if one value happened to be "a", every "a" in the entire string would be replaced.

So I opted to be safe and go to the index that the match starts at, remove the whole thing, then add the number back in at the same index

Comment: Right! I did not thought about that.