# VB.net check string for sub-string encapsulated by quotes

Tags: string, vb.net, substring

My goal is to determine whether a provided string contains a string encapsulated by double quotes -- like such:    **My dog is "named Max"**
If it does have such a string I want to assign it to a variable.

The double quotes may be at one end or the other or entirely within the string.
While I understand how to search for the quotes themselves or how to count the occurrences of them...I do not know how to search for a sub string found between two instances of the quote character.

```
Dim originalSearchText as String = "My dog Is ""named Max"""
Dim containsDblQuotes As Boolean
Dim selectedSubString As String = Nothing

  If originalSearchText.Contains("""") Then
    containsDblQuotes = True
  Else
    containsDblQuotes = False
  End If
```

I need for the above to assign the string "named Max" to the variable called selectedSubString.

Comment: Check out [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955882/how-can-i-get-the-characters-between-2-other-characters)

Comment: Can there be multiple sets of quotes strings i.e. `My dog is "named Max" and "has black fur"`?

Comment: @djv There could be. But if I got the simpler single version I could probably work out the sets of quotes version.

Comment: @nickmoriarty that is good but the two things that you are searching for in that example are different "[" and "]". The quote is the same for the starting and ending character. seems a little different?

Comment: You can find the first double-quote with IndexOf. Then the next with the overload of [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a starting position. Repeat as needed.

Comment: @AndrewMorton giving that a go. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String.Split

```
Dim originalSearchText As String = "My dog Is ""named Max"""
'Dim originalSearchText As String = """named Max"" my dog is"
'Dim originalSearchText As String = "My dog Is ""named Max"" and ""has black fur"""
Dim splitString = originalSearchText.Split({""""c}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Dim selectedSubString As String = splitString(1)
```

It will return the string(s) in the odd-index location(s) of the resulting array `splitString`. In the third example, in addition to "named max", "has black fur" can be found in `splitString(3)`.

Comment: This is so excellent. Thank you for taking the time to assist me.