# Get numbers between chars in VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, char

it's my first question here.
I have a string for example like this:

```
some text [low=123 medium=456 high=789]
```

And I want to read all the numbers and type it in a label or something other like this:

```
label1. text = low 
label2. text = medium 
label3. text = high
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the characters between 2 other characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955882/how-can-i-get-the-characters-between-2-other-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Regex for this:

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("low=(?<low>\d+)\s+medium=(?<medium>\d+)\s+high=(?<high>\d+)")

label1.Text = RegexObj.Match(theString).Groups("low").Value 
label2.Text = RegexObj.Match(theString).Groups("medium").Value  
label3.Text = RegexObj.Match(theString).Groups("high").Value
```

Regex details

```
"low="            ' Match the characters “low=” literally
"(?<low>"         ' Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “low”
   "\d"           ' Match a single digit 0..9
      "+"         ' Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")"  
"\s"              ' Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   "+"            ' Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"medium="         ' Match the characters “medium=” literally
"(?<medium>"      ' Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “medium”
   "\d"           ' Match a single digit 0..9
      "+"         ' Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")"  
"\s"              ' Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   "+"            ' Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"high="           ' Match the characters “high=” literally
"(?<high>"        ' Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “high”
   "\d"           ' Match a single digit 0..9
      "+"         ' Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Cut the first and last character of you text
Split the result with space as seperator abd then split the resulting array with "=" as seperator.
Then you have yor result.
If the order is not fixt,  you have to check if the first array element is medium and  so on.